# probability measure on $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega$. Show that there exists probability measures $\mu_n$ on $\mathcal{A}~(n \in \mathbb{N})$ and $a_n>0$ such that for every set $A \in \mathcal{A}:$
$$\mu (A)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \mu_n (A).$$

Is there anyone can give me hints or show how to start proving this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true if $\mu(\Omega)=0$ so I preassume that $\mu(\Omega)\neq0$.

Find disjoint $A_n\in\mathcal A$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\Omega$ and $0<\mu(A_n)<\infty$.

Now have a look at measures like $\nu_n$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\mu(A\cap A_n)$.

They are finite and positive, so almost a probability measure.

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: what can i do to extent $\nu$ to be a probability measure?, since i have tried to modify it but it contradicts another condition

Comment: Define $a_n=\nu(\Omega)=\mu(A_n)$ and prescribe $\mu_n$ by $A\mapsto\nu(A)/a_n$.

Comment: Sorry, out of topic. If I have a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $f:\Omega \to [0, \infty]$ $\mathcal{A}-$measurable such that $\int_{\Omega}f~d\mu< \infty$. what can I do to show $\mu(E_n) < \infty$, if I define $E_n= \lbrace x \in \Omega ~|~ f(x)> \frac{1}{n} \rbrace$?

Comment: $\frac1n1_{E_n}\leq f$ Now take integrals on both sides to achieve $\frac1n\mu(E_n)\leq\int fd\mu<\infty$.