# Decomposition of measure in probability measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on sigma-algebra $A$ of subsets of $X$.

> How do I prove that there exist probability measures $(m_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ on $A$ and coefficients $c_n>0$ such that $$m(U)=\sum_n c_nm_n(U)?$$

I know that a $\sigma$-finite measure means that there exist subsets $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $X=\cup_n X_n$ and $m(X_n)<\infty$.
And a probability measure is such that $m_n(X)=1$.
But how can I use these to prove the statement?

Comment: Look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497906/probability-measure-on-sigma-algebra